# Swift - How to play a list of songs in an Array by AVAudioPlayer()

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to make a simple App of Music Player which contains songs that I can press Play button to play my Songs list Array, and I cannot figure out how to set Play button to play Song Array orderly. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var musicName: UILabel!

    var player = AVAudioPlayer()
    var songs = ["Rain", "Daze", "Temple of Thought"]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()        
    }


    func playingMusic() {


        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: songs[0], ofType: "mp3")
        let url  = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)

        player   = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url as URL)
        player.prepareToPlay()
        player.numberOfLoops = 1
        player.play()

    }

    @IBAction func play(_ sender: Any) {
        playingMusic() // This just play one song in my Songs List. How to set this function to play orderly song in my Songs List ?

    }
    @IBAction func Stop(_ sender: Any) {
        player.stop()
    }
}
```

Comment: take a look at 'AVQueuePlayer' - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avqueueplayer

Comment: Francesco and Sean gave you the hint, this should be the way to go. Alternatively you could use the delegate and respond to audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying. Inside that you could call your playingMusic function with an increased int parameter until you reach the array count.

Comment: @SeanLintern88  Thank you for your help, I am reading the document now and hope that i can solve it.

Comment: @Retterdesdialogs Thank you Retter, yeah i will definitely try your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check [AVQueuePlayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avqueueplayer), as the doc says you can use it to play a number of items in sequence.

Comment: Thank Francessco, i am working on it and it definitely helps.

Comment: copied my comment :/

Comment: Hi @SeanLintern88 no, I have written my answer in the same time of your comment, one minute before to be precise :)